# Manually adding member to a generic list after populating it with JSON data

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0

I am using this class that goes into a list.

```
public class Project
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Status { get; set; }
    public String ExternalUrl {get; set; } //new
}
```

I populate the list with JSON data that I get like this:

```
projects = data["value"].ToObject<List<Project>>();
```

The JSON data matches up to the members in the class EXCEPT a new one I added called ExternalUrl.

So I get the Id, Title, Status from JSON, but I'd like to build ExternalUrl using the Id I get from JSON. Something like this:

```
ExternalUrl = "http://yoursite.com/v/a/" + Id;
```

So the list would contain a bunch of objects like this:

Id
Title
Status
ExternalUrl

I tried this:

```
    foreach (Project project in projects)
    {
        project.ExternalUrl = "http://yoursite.com/" + project.Id;  
    }

    return projects;
```

This *does* work, but it seemed to slow everything down significantly.

Is there a more efficient/better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can `ExternalUrl` end up as a computed property (`get` only)?

Comment: @haim770 maybe?  Honestly I don't know what that means :)

Comment: @999cm999 `public string ExternalUrl { get { return "http://yoursite.com/" + this.Id; } }`

Comment: @999cm999, It means that instead of pre-populating its value, you can simply compute it upon `get`ting it. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx

Comment: @haim770 Oh ok, like Ahmed demonstrated below and Jason P above? Thanks

Comment: @999cm999 My snippet and Ahmed's are different. Mine is a property with only a getter, his is a method that returns a string. Either can work depending on what you need. If you want to serialize the data later, you'll want a property.

Comment: @999cm999, What Ahmed demonstrated is a method, not a property. It's up to you to decide which one is more expressive.

Comment: Unrelated question: is this Newtonsoft JSON.NET or something different used to convert JSON data to object?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek Yes I'm using the Newtonsoft JSON.NET library.

Comment: I made it a method because some JSON Libraries have issues with get-only properties, and I didn't know which library you are using in my answer time

Comment: @JasonP Does that mean I can get rid of my foreach loop?

Comment: @999cm999 Yes it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can this help you?

```
public class Project{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Status { get; set; }
     public string GetExternalUrl() {
         return "http://yoursite.com/" + Id; 
     }
}
```

**EDIT:**
as as side note, if you will access the same project instance more than once, you better construct the external url string once instead of recreating it every time, the new code should be like

```
public class Project{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Status { get; set; }

     string _externalUrl;
     public string GetExternalUrl() {
         if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_externalUrl))
             _externalUrl = "http://yoursite.com/" + Id; 

         return _externalUrl;
     }
}
```

More ugly, but more efficient if you will access the same instance multiple times

Comment: It's better to replace it with property I think so it could be used by JSON serializer.

Comment: I made it a method because some JSON Libraries have issues with get-only properties, and I didn't know which library is being used while answering

Comment: if data will be serialized again and JSON library is okay with get-only properties, so it is better to be a get-only property